# Check if custom tooltip's upper left is within bounds

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

How can I check if a custom tooltip's upper left fits within the map bounds?
I am using the code below but something is not right because 'myLatLng' is never within the map bounds. Thank you for your help in advance.

```
var scale = Math.pow(2, map.getZoom());
var nw = new google.maps.LatLng(
    map.getBounds().getNorthEast().lat(),
    map.getBounds().getSouthWest().lng()
);
var worldCoordinateNW = map.getProjection().fromLatLngToPoint(nw);
var worldCoordinate = map.getProjection().fromLatLngToPoint(marker.getPosition());
var pixelOffset = new google.maps.Point(
    Math.floor((worldCoordinate.x - worldCoordinateNW.x) * scale),
    Math.floor((worldCoordinate.y - worldCoordinateNW.y) * scale)
);

var myLatLng = map.getProjection().fromPointToLatLng(pixelOffset);

if (map.getBounds().contains(myLatLng)) {
 // it's within bounds
}
```

Comment: Surely the "position of marker anchor" IS the position of the marker, ie `marker.getPosition()`?

Comment: I need to work out the pixel position of the marker anchor

Comment: Why should you want to convert to px coordinates then back to latLng just to work out whether a marker is within bounds? The `.contains()` method, where you end up, will operate on the marker position directly; `if( map.getBounds().contains(marker.getPosition()) ) { /*it's within bounds */ }`

Comment: @Beetroot-Beetroot, because I display a custom tooltip atop the marker so I need to check if the tooltip is within the bounds.

Comment: Was the tooltip not worth mentioning in the question?

Comment: @Beetroot-Beetroot, I thought that it would complicate my question if I also added the bit about the tooltip

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I worked it out and this is the solution I used.

```
var proj = map.getProjection();
var bounds = map.getBounds();
var scale = Math.pow(2, map.getZoom());             

var anchorPoint = proj.fromLatLngToPoint(marker.getPosition());
// tlc == top left corner (of tooltip)
var tlcPoint = new google.maps.Point(
  (anchorPoint.x * scale) / scale,  
  ((anchorPoint.y * scale) - marker.getIcon().size.height - tooltip.getHeight()) / scale
);
var tlcLatLng = proj.fromPointToLatLng(tlcPoint);

if ( ! bounds.contains(tlcLatLng) ) {
 bounds.extend(tlcLatLng);
 map.fitBounds(bounds);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have a syntax error and typo in your code:

```
if (map.getBounds().countains(myLatLng) {
 // it's within bounds
}
```

Should be

```
if (map.getBounds().contains(myLatLng)) {
 // it's within bounds
}
```

Comment: Thank you for spotting that. The spelling error occurred while adding my question on this website but it's not the reason why my code is not working properly.

Comment: Your updated question is still missing a closing `)` - is that also just a mistake while adding your question, or a genuine error in your code?  Run your actual JS through something like JSLint; Google Maps is very unforgiving of JS errors

Comment: Yes the closing ) was also a mistake while adding my question